# HL7 in WSO2 ESB - which versions are supported?

Tags: wso2, esb, hl7, hl7-v3, hl7-v2

I am evaluating the ESB of WSO2 and I saw that there is HL7 feature which you can install to enable HL7 transport.
Is it possible to specifiy the version in the use of the feature? At some point of my application I have to distinguish between HL7 version 3 and HL7 version 2.6.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use Hapi library as our HL7 parser, which doesn't support HL7V3 messages.So, in ESB it supports only 2.x versions..

Comment: thank you for the information, if I change the source code of the wso2-HL7-Feature and replace the HAPI-Parser with another API which supports version 3, then there should be no problem, right? This means I would change the feature and install the new in-house feature.

Comment: You need to do some code level changes also.The message builder/formatter uses hapi library..So, you need to change them and rebuild the jar..

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 ESB version 4.7.0 supports HL7 version 2.x standards.

Thanks.